# stop matlab line plots from overlapping

Tags: matlab, plot

I plot many lines on top of one another, using `plot` and `hold on`
however i want one of the lines to be shifted a bit if it falls on another line.
for example in the following case:

```
plot(1:100); hold on; plot(-100:100,abs(-100:100))
```

i want it to be clear that there are 2 plots here
i tried to simply increase x values for different plots but this skews the data too much

```
for z=1:numberofplots
plot((1:size(locations,2))+0.1*z,locations(z,:)','color', altclrz(z,:));
end
```

Comment: As a workaround you could use linestyles like `'--o'` that leave underlying lines visible.

Comment: what about using another dimension? plot using `plot3` and give each plot a distinct z value. Then set the view angle to some appropriate value.

Comment: @Deve that doesnt work, the spaces fall on the same area in all plots

Comment: @ItamarKatz i couldnt find that "appropriate value" that looked better than what i already have

Comment: @Daniel Use `--r` for one line and `-b` for another, for example. Then you will see the red line underneath the blue one. Of course, this only works for a limited number of lines.

Comment: @Daniel You can try increasing the line width for one of the plots.

Answer (score 5):

You can differentiate the curves in several ways:

**-1- Skewing the data**

As you said, you could shift the data a bit. I would suggest fixing your axis and then calculating how many units in linewidth is so you get a very tight fit, like this:

```
lineWidth = 5;

figure(33);
clf;
subplot(1,2,1);
h = plot(myData, 'linewidth', lineWidth);
xlim([1,5]);
ylim([1,5]);
title('Original');

myData = meshgrid(1:5)';

myLimDiff = diff(ylim);
set(gca,'units', 'pixels');
myPos = get(gca, 'position')
myWidthHeight= myPos(3:4)

PixelsPerUnit =myWidthHeight(2)./ myLimDiff;
myDataSkewed = myData + meshgrid(-2:2)*1/PixelsPerUnit(1)*lineWidth;

subplot(1,2,2);
plot(myDataSkewed, 'linewidth', lineWidth);
xlim([1,5]);
ylim([1,5]);
title('Skewed');
```

Result:

[image]

**-2- Using solid lines and Dashes**

As someone else noted in the comments, you could you a dashed line over a solid line, or some combination of styles.

**-3- Using different line thickness**

Use different line widths with the thickest on the bottom:

```
figure(54);
clf
hold all
for ind = 10:-3:1
    plot(1:5, 'linewidth', ind);
end
```

[image]

**-4- Use separate plots for each line with a twist**

Another way to call out each line is to plot each line in a subplot but to plot all the data in gray first. This way you can see where all the lines are with each particular line called out:

[image]

```
figure(55);
clf
data = rand(3);

for ind = 1:3    
    subplot(1,3,ind);
    plot(data, 'linewidth', 4, 'color', [1 1 1]*.75);
    hold on
    plot(data(:,ind), 'linewidth', 2);
end
```

Comment: the problem with most of the ideas so far is that I have quite a lot of plots, usually over 50. this makes 2, 3 and 4 inapplicable. 1 looks very nice I'll check it right away. (I hope it works if the plots are done separately using hold)

Comment: +1 for idea 4, even if the OP can't use it, I think that it is a great solution.