# Arbitrary placing on nodes (layers) in Matlab graph

Tags: matlab

The following code using `hold on` overlaps completely a graph on the other;

```
hold on
m = {'a'};
n = {'b'};
v = {'c'}; 
w = {'d'};
g1 = graph(m,n);
g2 = graph(v,w);
p1 = plot(g1);
p2 = plot(g2);
p1.NodeLabel = {'', ''};
p2.NodeLabel = {'', ''};
p2.LineStyle = {'none'};
p1.MarkerSize = [10 20];
p2.MarkerSize = [20 10];
axis off
```

[image]

in case I need visibility of both placed on nodes (like the lower nodes) is there any solution (or trick) instead of hold on?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397484/stop-matlab-line-plots-from-overlapping

Answer (score 1):

by the way so far this trick seems to be working;

dividing the `total_matrix` to the `minor_matrix` and `major_matrix`, and just put the `major_matrix` on first layer, then make `NodeColor` the variable.

[image]